# How to keep apps from adding themselves to login items?

Tags: install, login-items

Today, I noticed that there were several "login items" that I'm 99.99999% certain I did not add.  I figure those items added themselves when I installed them (they were probably installations that required authentication).

Of course, I can always check "login items" every time that I install an app (if the installer asked for authentication), but I'd prefer to lock "login items" altogether.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 6):

Update*

if you do a get info on the ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist file and tick the lock checkbox.

[image]

No changes will be written to the file. Therefor on next login there will be no additions.

I just tested this and it worked. But cannot guarantee that this may or may not be a good thing to do.  I my self will use my Answer below.

---

You can set a [launchAgent](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) to watch for changes on the ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist file

In my example here I use a launchAgent to watch for the change and then run a command to notify me. In this case I use the command tool [growlnotify](http://growl.info/extras.php#growlnotify)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>loginItems</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/growlnotify</string>
        <string>-n</string>
        <string>login items change</string>
        <string>-m</string>
        <string>login items change</string>
        <string>-s</string>
    </array>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/USERNAME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I actually made this using [lingon](http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) which take some of the pain out of making launchAgent.

The command I run is :`/usr/local/bin/growlnotify -n "login items change" -m "login items have been changed" -s`

Note this is a simple example. And you should remember that any changes may take a short while to be written to the plist. But my tests have shown it to work.

Comment: Updated  my answer

Comment: did you mean "launchAgent", not "lunchAgent"?

Comment: lol. Clearly I was thinking of food at the time..

Comment: This worked for me, but I noticed that after running the offending app, it would initially appear under "login items" until I restarted my machine.

Comment: My Mac doesn't have a `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist` item. Granted this answer is six years old. There is a `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist item`?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:

Add that application to your dock. Right click on the dock icon -> options -> uncheck "open at Login".

If you don't want the application on your dock afterward, just drag it off.