# How to determine what is modifying com.apple.loginitems.plist?

Tags: login-items

The application **DISH Anywhere Slingplayer** (currently at v. 1.1.0.386) automatically attempts to add itself to the current user's Login Items, both at login time and at app startup time (I use [Little Flocker](https://www.littleflocker.com/), so I see the attempt to modify `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist`.)

I am trying to disable this, without uninstalling or [locking com.apple.loginitems.plist](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84915/how-to-keep-apps-from-adding-themselves-to-login-items), but I can't figure out what setting/code is pulling this really crappy stunt.

Where can I start poking around to find the offending entries? (I already looked in `/System/Library/StartupItems/`, `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/` and `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` but nothing obvious in there.)
[OS X 10.11.6]

Answer (score 1):

The only other 2 locations I can think of that are Mac related and not within the app settings itself are `/Library/LaunchDaemons` (which you may have already checked when you checked `/Library/LaunchAgents`) and the preferences files for the app. If you have an appropriate application to examine them (like Xcode) you could take a look at:

- `~/Library/Preferences/com.slingmedia.plist`
- `~/Library/Preferences/com.slingmedia.setupassistant.plist`
- `~/Library/Preferences/com.slingmedia.slingplayer.plist`

I personally do not have a slingbox or the app installed so I can't examine them myself but it would be a really 'crappy stunt' - as you put it so elegantly :) - if the app is designed to execute some code every time it launches to re-initiate the login item settings.

Comment: No such .plist files in ~/Lib/Prefs/, and nothing in LaunchDaemons folders - very odd… This functionality really is happening - others have verified on the Dish Forums.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try to "catch" whatever event/process is installing the startup item, I highly suggest giving [BlockBlock](https://objective-see.com/products/blockblock.html) (free) a try. It will pop up immediately upon any injection of a launchagent/daemon and give you the option to block/allow. Works fine on 10.12.4.

Another tool that is very useful for working with launchd is [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/). It's not free, but the trial is not crippled in any way. If you simply can't prevent the Slingplayer from adding itself to startup, you might be able to at least neuter the plist by setting its "RunAtLoad" flag to false.